# uBlock filter to change style field of a div tag

Tags: ublock-origin

aliexpress uses this tag to split the search results into 4 columns:

```
<div class="product-snippet_ProductSnippet__grid__w6hatm product-snippet_ProductSnippet__vertical__w6hatm SnowSearchProductFeed_List__grid__vmkcs" style="grid-template-columns:repeat(4, 1fr)">
```

I want to change it to 6 columns.

I've tried the following in uBlock filters:

```
aliexpress.ru##.product-snippet_ProductSnippet__grid__w6hatm product-snippet_ProductSnippet__vertical__w6hatm SnowSearchProductFeed_List__grid__vmkcs:style(grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr) !important)
```

it does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
aliexpress.ru##.SnowSearchProductFeed_List__grid__vmkcs:style(grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr) !important)
```